# Finding the slope of the line $y-9=3(x+2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the slope of the line given by $y-9=3(x+2)$.

I haven't got very far on this. I completely lost right now.

Comment: with a few simple steps you can put it in form y=mx+b, and then the slope is m.

Comment: In general, the first step to help yourself is input "[the topic] wiki" to google. If you input "slope wiki" to google, the first link there should be [slope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope) on wiki. Visit that page and compare the standard form of line to what you have. Can you rewrite what you have to standard form $y = mx+b$? If you can do that, the slope will be the value of $m$.

Comment: You may differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ and find $\frac{dy}{dx}$. (Since you tagged the question with [tag:calculus])

Comment: It would be faster to ask on another website like [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=slope+of+line+y-9%3D3%28x%2B2%29). Also no downvotes there.

Answer (score 2):

first you need to multiply the numbers $3$ and $(x+2)$ as $$3(x+2) = 3x+ 3*2 = 3x+ 6. $$ After we can add 9 to both sides and notice y-9+9 = y because the 9s cancel. Then we have left $y = 3x+6+9 = 3x+ 15$. The slope is given by the coefficient in front of the $x$. Here $m=3$. You can add like terms. You can add x's with x's and numbers with numbers. We leave $3x+15$ as is because we don't know what $x$ is, it can take many values. We add variables together For example 2x+3x = (2+3)x = 5x. This is known as distributive property.

Comment: Word of advice for the future. It's best not to answer questions like this one that so thoroughly break the rules of the site (answering in itself is against site guidelines). The question will soon be closed, and answers to questions like this one often earn more downvotes than upvotes.

Comment: @C-RAM sorry he obviously needed some help

Comment: Fair enough; I do admire your kindness and drive to help, though as some of the above comments hint at, this website is not the place to ask "just do all the work for me" questions of this sort. MSE has a very specific purpose (and set of rules), and the OP gets nothing in the long run if we just do their homework for them. Best course of action is to leave a comment explaining how to improve the question and come back to answer if they make an effort to improve it. That's it; I won't bug you any more. Happy holidays, and welcome to MSE. : )

Comment: @C-RAM I do apologize next time I will make sure to generalize question to not provide exact answers